# IOS button color is blue instead of black?

Tags: html, css, ios, button, colors

Text in HTML Buttons turns blue on iOS devices, but the button color works fine on windows, android, etc. This is my website that is having the color issue if it helps. https://maryg36.github.io/Zelda-Project/

I added "color: black" directly to the buttons in CSS and it did not work, I then added "color: inherit"  as that worked for others on stack, but that did not work for me.

Comment: Questions which rely on links aren't allowed on Stack Overflow. Questions need to be self-contained so that they might be useful to someone else in five years' time. You can edit your question to improve it. In the meantime, I'm voting to close it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Viewed your page in the iOS Simulator, and adding this line of CSS fixes the problem:

```
.zeldaMusicBtn {color: black;}
```

The blue colour is coming from Safari's default style sheet, and your page is not overriding that anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for helping me! I did write "color: black", but when I looked on the dev tools, it also doesn't show I wrote it. This is my CSS code                                          
 .zeldaMusicBtn {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: rgb(204, 51, 51);
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: black solid 0.2rem;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

Comment: Probably just your browser caching an old version of your `styles.css` file. Try clearing your cache and see if that helps.

Comment: Maybe not the best way, but " color: black !important; " worked. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I can see the updated stylesheet now, including `black !important`. But my guess is that adding the `!important` simply created a new version of your CSS file and helped to clear the old version out of your cache. I also guess that if you now remove the `!important`, it will still continue to work as you want it to. Cache invalidation is one of the oldest problems in computer science. I'm a professional web developer and I have to clear various caches multiple times per day in order to see my updates immediately.

Comment: I will remember to clear cache more often as well. Thank you for your responses!